# Use an array method (e.g. map) on a union of different array types without casting to any[] or to []

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes a union of two or more array types. E.g.

```
type MyArray = string[] | number[];

const someFunc = (array: MyArray) => array.map(x => x.toString());
```

This is the error message:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
Type '
<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[] |
<U>(callbackfn: (value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]
'
has no compatible call signatures.
```

Questions:

1. What is the `expression` in the error message?
2. What is the type of the `expression`?
3. How can we specify the type of that `expression`?

This is what I have tried:

```
const someFunc01 = (array: MyArray) =>
  (array as any[]).map(x => x.toString());

const someFunc02 = <T extends MyArray, U extends T[number]>(array: U[]) =>
  array.map(x => x.toString());

const someFunc03 = (array: MyArray) =>
  (array as []).map(x => x.toString());
```

To be clear, these are the use cases:

```
someFunc01([10, 20, 30]); // must compile
someFunc01(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']); // must compile
someFunc01(['foo', 10, 'baz']); // must not compile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the expression in the error message?

it's `array.map`, the array method which you are trying to call for `array` parameter in `someFunc`

> What is the type of the expression?

it's a union of two types, one for `map()` in `string[]` array, another one for `map()` in `number[]` array

> How can we specify the type of that expression?

```
type E = (string[] | number[])['map'];
```

gives this type in the [playground popup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Atype%20E%20%3D%20(string%5B%5D%20%7C%20number%5B%5D)%5B'map'%5D%3B%0D%0A)

```
type E = (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])
```

This is a long-standing issue in TypeScript - it does not allow to call methods on union types, even if all the members in the union have methods with the same name, but different, although appropriate, signatures.

For now, you have to use type assertion in the implementation like this

```
type StringOrNumberArrayMap = (string | number)[]['map'];

const someFunc = (array: MyArray) => (array.map as StringOrNumberArrayMap)(x => x.toString());
```

It will not affect the interface of `someFunc`, all your examples  for `someFunc` should compile (or not compile) as intended.

This might, or might not be fixed in the next versions of the compiler (in 3.3 or later), see [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011)